# Cron Job to delete g-zip files older than N days not working

Tags: shell, unix, cron

On a cPanel hosting, we set up a shell script as a cron-job to auto create backups of our site, and also to auto-delete files older than 4 days.

The backup part works excellently well, however, the auto-delete never seems to work, so we resort to manually delete files.

Below is included the script. Any pointers as to what might be the reason for the auto-delete not working will be highly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

# create the backups
tar czf ~/backups/backup_public_html`date +%Y_%m_%d`.tgz ~/public_html

# delete files older than 4 days from /backups
find ~/backups -type f -mtime +4 -exec rm {} \
```

Comment: Is it a typo or are you missing a semicolon at the end of the find command?

Comment: not a typo, but I don't think that might be the issue

Comment: Thank you, that was part of it.